# while running ICA in eeglab only .set file is created but not .fdt file. Looking forward for solution

Tags: eeglab

we are running ICA on EEGLAB on an hd eegdata set to assess ERP. However, few eeg files could able to generate only .set file but not .fdt files.
How to solve this problem ?

seeking solution to create both .set and .fdt file